# Once an insight is available for any video can we get the same insight translated into any other language?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-video-indexer

We are already using Azure but limited to English only
However, now we want to expand and add a feature where the user can select a language from a list of languages to translate the available insights.

Now our question is that we do get video insights in English
so once an insight is available can we translate it to any language, through an API right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes.
When you have an indexed video and you call the Get-Video-Index API with another language, it will translate the video into that language (if not already available is that language).
Notice there are throttling limitations on that API.